# Implement Vertical sliding div using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic structure on html like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span2">
      <!--Sidebar content-->
    </div>

    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I would like to add a toggle button that will hide/show the sidebar (slide would be vertically).
If the sidebar is hidden, I would like the content to use the entire area (which would likely be span12). If the sidebar is shown, everything will be revert back.

My approach would be, I will be toggling the span10 and span12 class of the body content area depending on the state of the sidebar.

Is there a better way to do it?

thanks!

Comment: Please see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154744/twitter-bootstrap-collapse-group-only-on-phone which partly answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow converted my answer to a comment so I will post a more complete answer.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="collapse-group">
      <div class="span2">
        <!--Sidebar content-->
      </div>
      <a class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".span2">Toggle</a>
    </div>

    <div class="span10">
      <!--Body content-->
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

span2 will now be collapsed by default and if you click the button it will expand vertically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

How about making the span10(body content) cover the whole section?